# Can you add Threat to create temporary assets in Dune?

Tags: modiphius-2d20, dune-adventures-in-the-imperium

The Dune rules say that it costs 2 Momentum to create a temporary asset. It doesn't mention that you can add to Threat to do so, but quite frankly the book is NOT good at cross-referencing. So I may have missed it.

Question: **Can players add 2 to Threat instead of spending 2 Momentum to create a temporary asset?**

Why do I want to know this? Well basically the game stalled when the narrative (there is a dead guard armed with a pistol) clashed with the mechanics. The players wanted to grab guns from the dead guys and shoot back at folk who were attacking them.

That was fine when there was Momentum to spend... spend the 2 points, then bingo - you have a temporary asset of 'Pistol'. The PC can now shoot at people.

But no Momentum left = no pistol asset can be created. No pistol asset = cannot take part in ranged combat.

The core rules specifically say assets make a thing ***possible OR impossible***. You can punch someone without needing any asset other than your own fist. But you can't shoot someone without a gun asset. Because pointing your finger at them and making pew-pew-pew noises doesn't hack it! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You cannot add Threat to create a temporary asset

Page 155 of the rules lists the ways the players can add Threat under the **Adding to Threat** heading:

> Player characters can add to the Threat pool in the following ways:
>
> - **Buying d20s**: As noted earlier in this chapter, characters may buy bonus d20s for skill tests by adding points to Threat instead of spending Momentum. (...)
> - **Complications**: Whenever a player character suffers one or more complications on a skill test, they or the gamemaster may choose to add two points to the Threat pool to ignore a complication.
> - **Escalation**: At times, the gamemaster (or the rules) may state that a specific action or decision risks escalating the situation, making it more dangerous or unpredictable. If a character performs an action that risks escalation, they immediately add one point of Threat to the pool.

These are all the ways listed that player characters can add Threat (the gamemaster has some more). Creating a temporary asset is not on the list. Furthermore the secion on creating a temporary asset (page 152) says:

> **Create a Trait** allows you to define a new fact about the scene or situation. Spending **2 points of Momentum** either creates a brand-new trait, changes an existing one, or removes one currently in play. (...)
> **Create an Asset** works in the same way as creating a trait, but there are some limitations to the kinds of assets you can create. An asset created has a Quality of 0, and it should be useful in the current type of conflict. Assets created in this way are temporary and cease to exist at the end of the scene.

Spending Threat is not given as one of the options to create a temporary asset (or any kind of trait, really). The only way is to spend 2 points of Momentum.

To avoid situations like the one you describe, you can save momemtum to use on them later on. Page 151 explains this:

> Whenever you score more successes than you needed on a skill test, each extra success becomes Momentum, (...). Any Momentum you don’t spend **can be saved**, and saved Momentum goes into a group pool for everyone to use. **Up to 6 points of Momentum can be saved** like this.

Comment: Thank you. You are probably correct on this. However, your examples are not the only ways to add Threat. Like I said, the book is not good at cross-referencing. For instance on page 137 you can add Threat to create supporting NPCs. And on page 136 you can add Threat to sacrifice an NPC. And on p165 you can add to Threat to keep the initiative. They really needed a comprehensive list of "everything you can do with Threat" on one page! :-)

Comment: @DrBob Yes, you are right on that -- the creation of supporting characters can be paid for in Momentum or Threat, and should be on that list.